Assign GitLab Runner to a project as "Assigned Project Runner"
GitLab used to have a nice menu where you could assign a runner to a project. After some updates, it is now nearly impossible to find. Every once in a while, I have to delete and reinstall the runners, and now I cannot find it despite having clicked on every link and menu in GitLab.
It used to be here:
Visit your project's Settings > CI/CD, find the runner you wish to enable/disable, and click "Enable for this project" or "Disable for this project."

Where on earth do I enable a new registered runner for the projects? I just need the "Shared Runners" to show up under "Assigned Project Runners." Why have they made this so difficult?

